# Problem regarding a twice continuously differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ $\in$ $C^2[a,b]$ with $f(a) = f(b) = 0$. It is to be proved that $\forall x \in [a,b]$, there exists $c_x$ $\in$ $(a,b)$ such that $f(x) = \frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{2} f''(c_x)$.

I presume that this is an application of Rolle's Theorem choosing another function which is related to $f(x)$ in some way. I am not being able to select this new function.

Comment: Can you not choose $c_x = \dfrac{2f(x)}{(x - a)(x - b)}$?

Comment: I did. For $x \in (a, b)$, you do see that the only possibility for $c_x$ is what I have written, right? Of course, you'd have to prove that this $c_x$ does lie in the interval $(a, b)$ but at least I told you what $c_x$ *has* to be. "I am not being able to select this new function." made it look like you did not think of that either.

Comment: Of course not. But $x \mapsto c_x$ indeed is. Which is what you want.

Comment: I apologise. Please see the edit. The question was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conclusion is surely true if $x=a$ or $x=b$.

For fixed $x_0 \in (a, b)$ the idea is to define $p(x) = (x-a)(x-b)$ as the polynomial interpolating $f$ at $x=a$ and $x=b$, and use that to construct a function
$$
 h(x) = f(x)p(x_0) - f(x_0)p(x) 
$$
with three distinct zeros in $[a, b]$. Now repeated application of Rolle's theorem shows that the second derivative has a zero in $c \in (a, b)$, i.e.
$$
 0 = h''(c) = f''(c)(x_0-a)(x_0-b) - 2f''(x_0)
$$
which is the desired conclusion.